# Possible Javascript selector (no framework) to get array of elements using array key naming syntax

Tags: javascript, dom, yui, css-selectors

I have a form where the inputs have names such as:

```
unit_price[1]
unit_price[2]
```

The only way I've found to access them from javascript is using:

```
document.getElementsByName("unit_price[1]")[0]
```

I was wondering if there is a way to access them as a single array in one selector.

I'm looking for a pure javascript way to do this, but the page does have the YUI 2 framework loaded, in case there is a one step way of doing it using yui syntax.

Comment: HTMLFormElement.elements would be a big help here. You'd have to loop over the elements collection itself, and then pass an iterator (`i`, for example) to another HTMLFormElement.elements call. Ex: `HTMLFormElement.elements["unit_price[" + i + "]"];`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [YUI2 docs](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/selector/):

```
var nodes = YAHOO.util.Selector.query('input[name^=unit_price]');
```

Comment: Yeah, I just found that.  There docs leave something to be desired. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here's a native solution using [`querySelectorAll()`<sup>*[docs]*</sup>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Document.querySelectorAll) :

```
document.querySelectorAll("[name^=unit_price]");
```

Has pretty good browser support.

http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_core.html

[image]

Good idea to prefix the selector with `input` like [@davin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/448296/davin) did in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7590360/possible-javascript-selector-no-framework-to-get-array-of-elements-using-array/7590412#7590412).

Comment: +1 because I've never heard of this and it's pretty awesome. I'm giving davin the answer because I ended up using his exact solution although I found it on my own.

Comment: As a note, I'm fairly sure that YUI3 will use querySelectorAll under the hood if it's available and revert to an in-code solution otherwise. I don't believe YUI2 works this way, though.